# googlemap static gps coordinates street

Tags: dictionary, static, gps, coordinate

I am trying to create a Java project and I'd like to know if it was possible to retrieve the coordinates of the nearest street according to a GPS point. Thanks to googlemap static or other free support.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recently found geopy, it is developed in Python. I dont know if it helps.

https://code.google.com/p/geopy/